# ROS with python virtual environment

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS noetic on my ubuntu machine using apt command. It uses root python installation (python3.8) like `/usr/bin/python3`. All ROS related python modules like  `rospkg, rospy, cv_bridge` have been installed for this interpretor. Now, as I work on other big projects, I need to install many python modules and even different python versions. So, I use conda or python venv environment for that. **How can I run those projects in ROS since it uses the root installation interpretor?** If I activate a virtual env, the ROS node does not run and shows error like

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "rospkg"

What is the best way to handle different python environments along with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/413037/ros-with-python-virtual-environment/) by [zrahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/109467/zrahman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2023-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

To run the nodes in a virtual environment of your choice, you should change the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (i.e. the very first line in your script which should look something like `#!/usr/bin/env python`) of your scripts so to point to the Python interpreter of the virtual environment.

As an example, if your virtual environment name is `venv` the first line in the script should be `#!/path/to/venv/bin/python3`. This is of course not so portable, as you are hardcoding the path in each and every script. A more flexible solution I have recently started to use is to set the virtual environment from the launch file with

```
 <arg name="venv" value="/path/to/venv/bin/python3" />
 <node> pkg="pkg" type="node.py" name="node" launch-prefix = "$(arg venv)" />
```

so if you migrate the venv, you just have to adapt the path to the interpreter in one place (i.e. the launch file).

As for the

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "rospkg"

you should be able to solve by simply activating your virtual environment and installing `rospkg` into it with `pip install rospkg`.

---

Originally posted by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) with karma: 221 on 2023-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2